# CakePHP Model instances confusion

Tags: php, cakephp, model

After debugging quite a bit, I noticed a really strange behaviour inside of CakePHP's (2.x) Model usage:

When I changed the Model ID and used read(), on a completly different object instance with a relation to the same Model, it overwrites the old Model data.

```
// set the user, by using the 'User' model
$this->User->id = 1;
$this->User->read();

print_r($this->User->data); // works correctly

$instance = new Notification(); // this has a relation to the 'User' model

print_r($instance->User->data); // == $this->User->data! why?!

$instance->User->id = 2;
$instance->User->read();

print_r($this->User->data); // == $instance->User->data!
```

Why are those Models connected with each other? Shouldnt they be completly separated, since it's a new instance? I mean, I'm setting the 'User' model for the Notification, not for $this

And if that's default behaviour - how can I read() data into different instances, whitout changing other models? Do I really need to manually create a new 'User' instance and store it somewhere in `$instance` to avoid this behaviour? That sounds rather ugly to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Model instances are singletons

The following two objects in the question are identical:

```
$this->User
$instance->User
```

Because they are literally the same object, the path used to access an object doesn't modify the behavior of the (User) object itself.

That's simply how [ClassRegistry::init](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init) works - it [stores a reference to model instances](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php#L193) - and will return the same object when queried for the same alias (className) again.

### Don't create models using new

Doing that is not normal - and will likely cause problems or at least confusion in the future. To get a reference to the Notification model, use [$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses), [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel) or `ClassRegistry::init` as appropriate.

### Don't use Model::read

> Do I really need to manually create a new 'User' instance

Absolutely not, that's not how models are intended to work with CakePHP. A model class is effectively the interface to the database, it's not a representation of a single row (except when calling save).

The simplest way to avoid a significant number of problems is to not use [Model::read](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read) at all, and instead use [any appropriate find call](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html); A more complete code example would permit a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared some things up for me. What I dont get at this point, is why in the cakePHP doc, everything is displayed using single model rows. What I mean is: If you create a new 'row' - you use `->create()` on the Model - and in many instances, you set `->id` on the model too (at least, in some examples). That seems like a rather confusing usage, if the model is supposed to represent the whole table but not a single row. So I always was guessing, that $this->User is a new User instance, not a Singleton - since $this->User->id is allowed.

Comment: When calling save is a specific use case where for that call the model represents an individual row, but generally speaking the model is a class that returns arrays - i.e. array(row, row2, row3) - the "row representation" of data is just an array, not the model object.